# Order of Control events

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Controls contain events.  For example, GridView contains: RowCreated, RowDataBound etc.

The following webpage suggest that control events execute between the Page.Load and Page.LoadComplete events: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx (see second table on the webpage).  Please confirm that this is true for postbacks and none postbacks.

Is there a way of establishing the order of control events e.g. does RowCreated execute before RowUpdating etc?  I realise that common sense can sometimes tell you which events will execute first (by looking at the name of the event), however I have found some controls were it does not.  I also realise that the reference material occasionally allows you to piece this together e.g. RowCancellingEdit says that the event executes: "before the GridView control exits edit mode".  I also realise that I could step through the code using Reflector and find out which events run first.

The question is: is there a way of telling from the reference material which run first?

Answer (score 1):

That's right. [This cheatsheet](http://files.meetup.com/1060099/asp.net_life_cycle_cheatsheet.pdf) might help.

Comment: Thanks, but the question asks about the lifecycle of Controls rather than the ASP.NET lifecycle.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "That's right"?  I am almost ready to mark your answer.